# How to use surf and sift detector in OpenCV for Python

Tags: python, opencv, surf

I was trying a code for feature matching which uses the function SURF(). Upon execution it gives an error saying "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SURF'".

How can I download this module for Python (Windows) and fix this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try **ORB** (Oriented FAST and Rotated BRIEF) as an alternate to SURF in open cv. It almost works as good as SURF and SIFT and it's *free* unlike **SIFT** and **SURF** which are *patented* and can't be used commercially. 
You can read about it more in opencv-python documentation
[here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_orb/py_orb.html)

Here's the sample code for your ease

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img1 = cv2.imread('text.png',cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # queryImage
img2 = cv2.imread('original.png',cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # trainImage
# Initiate SIFT detector
orb = cv2.ORB_create()

# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)
# create BFMatcher object
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
# Match descriptors.
matches = bf.match(des1,des2)

# Sort them in the order of their distance.
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance) 
# Draw first 10 matches.
img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches[:10],None, flags=2)

plt.imshow(img3),plt.show()
```

Comment: Does it work in opencv 2.7 or 2.4? Because I am getting the same error for ORB.

Comment: I've used it with open cv 3.0

Comment: Meanwhile, a few years into the future, the brilliant eggheads at openCV came up with another solution. 2 actually, KAZE and AKAZE. worth looking in to.

Comment: FYI, the patent for SIFT has run out and has thus been moved from the contrib  to the main repository. https://answers.opencv.org/question/227302/what-is-the-patent-status-of-surfsift/

Answer (score 0):

At first

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

and then use this hack to create sift object

```
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
```

Comment: I didn't know about that...gonna test it out!

Comment: SIFT and SURF are no longer included in OpenCV Version >= 3.
If you want to use them you have to manually compile OpenCV with contrib-modules and OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE CMake flag turned on.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv.imread('simple.jpg',0)
# Initiate FAST object with default values
fast = cv.FastFeatureDetector_create()
# find and draw the keypoints
kp = fast.detect(img,None)
img2 = cv.drawKeypoints(img, kp, None, color=(255,0,0))
# Print all default params
print( "Threshold: {}".format(fast.getThreshold()) )
print( "nonmaxSuppression:{}".format(fast.getNonmaxSuppression()) )
print( "neighborhood: {}".format(fast.getType()) )
print( "Total Keypoints with nonmaxSuppression: {}".format(len(kp)) )
cv.imwrite('fast_true.png',img2)
#Disable nonmaxSuppression
fast.setNonmaxSuppression(0)
kp = fast.detect(img,None)
print( "Total Keypoints without nonmaxSuppression: {}".format(len(kp)) )
img3 = cv.drawKeypoints(img, kp, None, color=(255,0,0))
cv.imwrite('fast_false.png',img3)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this source](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/16736) SIFT patent expired. SIFT should be implemented in the main opencv repository by now. At least `cv.SIFT_create()` init is working for me. I have opencv version `4.5.5`.

Example use with possible combination with other descriptors or detectors(alternative to `detectAndCompute()` function)

```py
import cv2 as cv
MAX_FEATURES = 5500
GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT = 0.03

def find_matches(im1, im2, detector_type: str, descriptor_type: str):
    # Convert images to grayscale
    im1Gray = cv.cvtColor(im1, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    im2Gray = cv.cvtColor(im2, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # init detector
    if detector_type == 'sift':
            detector = cv.SIFT_create(MAX_FEATURES)
    elif detector_type == 'fast':
            detector = cv.FastFeatureDetector_create()
    # ... ORB etc.
    # init descriptor
    if descriptor_type == 'sift':
            descriptor = cv.SIFT_create(MAX_FEATURES)

    keypoints1 = detector.detect(im1Gray, None)
    keypoints2 = detector.detect(im2Gray, None)

    # find descriptors with descriptor SIFT
    keypoints1, descriptors1 = descriptor.compute(im1Gray, keypoints1)
    keypoints2, descriptors2 = descriptor.compute(im2Gray, keypoints2)

    # BFMatcher object
    matcher = cv.BFMatcher(cv.NORM_L1, crossCheck=True)
    matches = list(matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2))

    # Sort matches by score
    matches.sort(key=lambda x: x.distance, reverse=False)
    # Remove not so good matches
    numGoodMatches = int(len(matches) * GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT)
    matches = matches[:numGoodMatches]

    # Draw top matches
    imMatches = cv.drawMatches(
        im1, keypoints1, im2, keypoints2, matches, None)
    cv.imwrite("matches.jpg", imMatches)
```